# Проблема с вводом scanf() на Си

Tags: c, ввод

Почему так работает код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void wait(int seconds)
{
    clock_t endwait;
    endwait = clock() + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    while (clock() < endwait)
    {
    }
}

int main()
{
    int H = 5000;
    const double g = 9.81;
    int t = 0;

    int h = H;

    do {
        printf("%d m\n", h);
        wait(1);
        t++;
        h = H - (g * (t * t) / 2);
    }
    while (h >= 0);
    printf("BABAH!\n"); 
    return 0;
}
```

а когда задет значение переменной Н пользователь то программа не работает 
Это код уже не работает

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void wait(int seconds)
{
    clock_t endwait;
    endwait = clock() + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    while (clock() < endwait)
    {
    }
}

int main ()
{       
    int H ;
    scanf("%d", H);
    const double g = 9.81;
    int t = 0;

    int h = H;

    do {
        printf("%d m\n", h);
        wait(1);
        t++;
        h = H - (g * (t * t) / 2);
    }
    while (h >= 0);
    printf("BABAH!\n"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что scanf (как в прочем любая другая функция) не может изменить значение переменной, переданной по значению (копия). Поэтому, передавайте адрес

вместо

```
scanf("%d",H);
```

нужно писать

```
scanf("%d",&H);
```

**P.S.**

вместо

```
printf("BABAH!\n");
```

лучше писать

```
puts("BABAH!");
```

и перевод строки будет, и быстрее, и безопаснее.